# Dill: After import, unpickling yields segmentation fault; what possible things could be going wrong?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

Recently, I upgraded to Big Sur on a Macbook Pro with a python3.9 brew install.  I use a virtual environment for developing.

I have a dill-pickled item that I have repickled with a fresh vm on this machine. Prior to importing anything, I can unpickle the item:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 06:20:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('item.pkl','rb') as pklstream:
...     item = dill.load(pklstream)
...
>>> item
<Foo object at 0x10d02eac0>
>>> quit()


(venv) $ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 06:20:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> from skimage.morphology import thin
>>> with open('item.pkl','rb') as pklstream:
...     item = dill.load(pklstream)
...
Segmentation fault: 11
(venv)$
```

This happens for `skimage` and for some unrelated local modules.  The best I can tell is that there is some underlying dependency that is changing the way pickle works when it is imported in this system.

I don't understand the degrees of freedom here -- what could be changing? What is impossible to change?

Where could this error be arising?

---

Since everything on the Mac side is more or less a custom install via a Brew, it is hard for me to perfectly re-install and re-cache everything.

Perhaps there are some settings I could set explicitly that would override whatever implicit behavior is incurred by the imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  What I expect is happening is that `dill` is writing to the pickle dispatch table (to register new object types it understands how to pickle), and `skimage` is also doing the same... and is replacing one of the dependencies of your serialized object with something incompatible.  So, depending on the order either package is first imported, it will result in a different pickle registry state (it's a dict of types mapped to serialization functions).

`dill` attempts to give you a workaround for this, with `dill.extend`.  So, you can remove `dill`-registered types from the registry with `dill.extend(False)`, and then (re-)inject them with `dill.extend(True)`.

I can't be certain this will fix what you are seeing, as you don't have a self-contained working example -- but this is the only thing that makes sense to me to be behind what is happening.

It's also possible to avoid some of these issues, for objects that you know to have a conflict in the registry... if you can use one of the `dill` serialization variants before you `dump` the object in question.  So, setting `dill.settings['recurse'] = True`, for example, may also store your object, but will not have the same serialization dependencies, and thus might not be affected by this same conflict in the registry.

Comment: I thought it must be something like this, and I was hoping you would answer.  I'll give that a shot -- `dill.settings['recurse'] = True` sounds like it will create an object that is more bootstrapped anyways (which is the idea).  After that, I'll clear out skimage as a dep.

Comment: As to a complete example, I'll work on it if there is time.  It seems as if skimage modifies the pickling process if it is merely touched (don't have to import anything specific).

Comment: Worked perfectly, btw.

Comment: Actually, skimage disables dill even after these changes.

Comment: @Chris: to be clear, toggling `dll.extend` does *not* work?  If that's the case, I'd really appreciate some small self-contained example as a `dill` GitHub issue.

Comment: Definitely; I'll see if I can reproduce it on its own tmrw.  My guess (at the moment): I suspect it has something to do with the items dill pickled having an skimage dependency themselves, and re-introducing the issue as they were unpickled.

Comment: I will say that it did work initially in a test case (when directly importing skimage, then unpickling), but it did not work in my runtime context with many functions imported from modules with skimage dependencies.  I got around it by thresholding the skimage versions.

Comment: @Chris: so this is probably a case of `skimage` messing with the registry without considering the impact on serialization codes like `dill` and `cloudpickle` -- they may have just tested against one of the two, or none.  I'd have to look into it.  I expect you are correct with the object type dependencies upon serialization.  You can see the serialization path with `dill.detect.trace(True)`. See the `dill` README for notes on how to read the trace.